# Form Array: Cannot find control with path: 'list -> description'

Tags: angular

Problem:

1. When I load the website, my console gives out the error: *Cannot find control with path: 'list -> description'*.
2. Clicking the Add Button reveals the added data into the array are "undefined" for both *description* and *status.*

What can be done to solve the two aforementioned problems?

Here are the codes:

**component.ts**

```
tableData: TableData[] = [
    { id: 'aaaaa', description: 'Go to market', status: true },
    { id: 'bbbbb', description: 'Buy groceries', status: true },
    { id: 'ccccc', description: 'Order pizza delivery', status: false },
  ];

  todoListForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getRandomID() {
    var text = "";
    var alphanumeric = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      text += alphanumeric.charAt(Math.random() * alphanumeric.length) +
        alphanumeric.charAt(Math.random() * alphanumeric.length) +
        alphanumeric.charAt(Math.random() * alphanumeric.length) +
        alphanumeric.charAt(Math.random() * alphanumeric.length) +
        alphanumeric.charAt(Math.random() * alphanumeric.length);

      console.log(text);

      return text;
    }
  }

  createForm(): void {
    this.todoListForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      list: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

    this.addList();
  }

  get list(): FormArray {
    return this.todoListForm.get('list') as FormArray;
  }

  addList() {
    const tdLForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: new FormControl(null),
      description: new FormControl (null, Validators.required),
      status: new FormControl (false),
    });

    this.list.push(tdLForm);
  }

  addRow(description: string, status: boolean) {
    const id = this.getRandomID();
    const newData: TableData = { id, description, status }

    this.tableData.push(newData);

    console.log('tableData', this.tableData);

    this.createForm(); //reset Form
  }

export interface TableData {
  id: string,
  description: string,
  status: boolean
}
```

---

**component.html**

```
{{ list.value | json}}
<form [formGroup]="todoListForm">
    <label> Description: </label>

    <div formArrayName="list">
        <div class="textbox">
            <input formControlName="description" placeholder="Enter description"
            type="text" maxlength="255" />
        </div>

        <input formControlName="status" type="checkbox" /> Completed

        <div class="button">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="addRow(list.value.description, list.value.status)">
                Add
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a loop since you're going through a formarray. Try:

```
<div formArrayName="list">
<div *ngFor="let listItem of todoListForm.controls.list.controls; let c=index" [formGroupName]="c">
```

Comment: With: `<div formArrayName="list">
<div *ngFor="let listItem of list.controls; let c=index" [formGroupName]="c">`